# E/flutter ( 2647): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have this error while connecting to a MySQL database in PHP, but while trying it on my [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), it works very well.

> E/flutter ( 2647): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:ecommercegetx/core/class/statusrequest.dart';
import 'package:ecommercegetx/core/functions/checkinternet.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Crud {
  Future<Either<StatusRequest, Map>> postData(String linkurl, Map data) async {
      var check = await checkInternet();
      print("###################################$check");
      print("###################################1$linkurl");
      print("###################################2$data");
      if (await checkInternet()) {
        print("checkedf");
        var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(linkurl), body: data);
        print("########################----33333333$response");
        if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
          Map responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
          return Right(responsebody);
        } else {
          return const Left(StatusRequest.serverfailure);
        }
      } else {
        return const Left(StatusRequest.offlinefailure);
      }
    }

  }
```

[image]

Here is the repository for full code (I couldn't add more code)
https://github.com/Y7gn/ecommercegetx

Comment: Are you using ```http://localhost:80/...``` as ```linkurl``` parameter too?

Comment: yes, I print it in the console

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75850459/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get your IP address and insert that instead of localhost.

Write `ipconfig` into your terminal and get your IP address from there. Then instead of localhost write down your IP in there.

Comment: it depends if the emulator is another device with its own IP